# Fixing Linear Search C#

Tags: c#

This method starts and the user gets a choice of the first or second file. How do I make it so that myArray changes depending on the result. Currently it says that myArray does not exist in the current context. If file 2 is choose then how do I set myArray to that file value?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```
  public static void search()   // Search for values
   {
 Console.WriteLine("1=Day 2=Depth");
 int operation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if (operation == 1)
    {
        String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Day_1.txt");
    }


   else if (operation == 2)
    {
        String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Months_1.txt");
    }


        Console.WriteLine("Enter number to search");
        String myString = Console.ReadLine();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        var regex = new Regex(myString);
        foreach (string array in myArray)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(array))
            {
                i++;
            }

            else if (regex.IsMatch(array))
            {
                j++; 
            }
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found match! - {1} Appeared {0} time(s)",i,myString);
        }

        else if(j == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Match for {0} in Data", myString);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Move your variables to the appropriate scope level. You declare it within that block, so it only lives within that block.

Comment: Type `String[] myArray = null;` directly below `int operation =` and change the calls from `String[] myArray = File.` to `myArray = File.`, then you can deal with the null reference exception when the user doesn't enter 1 or 2 later. This is a "scope" problem, things defined inside `{ }` are only accessible inside the same brackets. You want to scope `myArray` to the `search() {}` brackets, not the `if (operation == x) { } ` brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `myArray` within the scope of the `if` & `else`. You should instead declare it outside so that it can be accessed from anywhere in your function, like this:

```
String[] myArray = null;
if (operation == 1)
{
    myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Day_1.txt");
}
else if (operation == 2)
{
    myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Months_1.txt");
}
```

instead of

```
if (operation == 1)
{
    String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Day_1.txt");
}
else if (operation == 2)
{
    String[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("Data1/Months_1.txt");
}
```

You can read up more about scopes in C# [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked